# Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in C:\xampp\htdocs\otp\textlocal.class.php on line 102

Tags: php, html, one-time-password, email-verification

I am developing a new project for Event Management. For that, I need to implement OTP verification for mobile numbers for those who are registering for the event. I'm using textlocal API to send OTP and I'm getting the error as above.

Comment: Please post your code.Nobody can help you without looking at the code.

Comment: Seems like [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php) can help you

Answer (score 2):

In windows: in your `php.ini` file and remove the comment from **cURL** extension

change `;extension=curl` to `extension=curl`

---

For Ubuntu:

```
 sudo apt-get install php-curl
```

or

```
 sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

After you have saved the file you *must* restart your HTTP server software (e.g. Apache) before this can take effect.

and check into the phpinfo that your cURL extension is enabled or not

---

[image]